# How can I write this expression with box using MathJAX?

Tags: boxes, mathjax

I'm a beginner of LaTeX. I'm trying to write below expression using MathJAX.
[image: expression what I want to write]

I could write expression without box using array package.
But I couldn't draw a box within array. Can you help me please?
Thank you for your reading my question.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) While [tag:MathJax] uses LaTeX syntax, it uses Javascript and HTML's DOM model rather than TeX technology, making it mostly off topic for this site. You might try instead searching among the [questions tagged with mathjax on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjax), or in the official [mathjax-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/mathjax-users) Google group.

Comment: For LaTeX, you might try `logicsym` at http://www.cs.pomona.edu/~kim/CSC081S13/Auxiliary/ which claims to cover boxed proofs but I can't tell for sure what is meant. Neither can I find any licence whatsoever.

Comment: To close voters: I think the OP just meant to set everything in **math mode**, what looks to him/her as this MathJax syntax he/she is used to.

Comment: Please make your intentions more clear. You can edit your own question, also the title. Also it would help to provide some code without a box: Add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 7):

The following achieves it quite adequately:

```
$$
\begin{array}{l}
  \begin{array}{|l|}
    \hline
    \hspace{20pt} \rlap{q \rightarrow r} \hspace{200pt} \hbox{assumption} \\
    \begin{array}{|l|}
      \hline
      \hspace{14pt} \rlap{\neg q \rightarrow \neg p} \hspace{200pt} \hbox{assumption} \\
      \begin{array}{|l|}
        \hline
        \hspace{8pt} \rlap{p} \hspace{200pt} \hbox{assumption} \\
        \hspace{8pt} \rlap{\neg \neg p} \hspace{200pt} \neg \neg \hbox{i 3} \\
        \hspace{8pt} \rlap{\neg \neg q} \hspace{200pt} \hbox{MT 2, 4} \\
        \hspace{8pt} \rlap{q} \hspace{200pt} \neg \neg \hbox{e 5} \\
        \hspace{8pt} \rlap{r} \hspace{200pt} {\rightarrow} \hbox{e 1, 6} \\
        \hline
      \end{array} \\
      \hspace{14pt} \rlap{p \rightarrow r} \hspace{200pt} {\rightarrow} \hbox{i 3-7} \\
      \hline
    \end{array} \\
    \hspace{20pt} \rlap{(\neg q \rightarrow \neg p) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)} \hspace{200pt} {\rightarrow} \hbox{i 2-8} \\
    \hline
  \end{array} \\
  \hspace{26pt} \rlap{(q \rightarrow r) \rightarrow ((\neg q \rightarrow \neg p) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r))} \hspace{200pt} {\rightarrow} \hbox{i 1-9}
\end{array}
$$
```

Tested on [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com):

[image]

It assumes a `6pt` length for `\arraycolsep` - the gap between the vertical rule and the cell content inside an `array`. `\rlap` provides `r`ight over`lap`ping while `\hbox` sets content in text mode.